# fragment not showing up in MainActivity page

Tags: android, android-fragments

Good Day everyone, I using the left navigation bar and i use fragment for the activity in the navigation bar. But the problem is once I click on the activity, the fragment could not show up. I am not sure what is the problem.

**Main Activity**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nav_layout);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    initCollapsingToolbar();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    informationList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new AlbumsAdapter(this, informationList);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 
2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2,  
dpToPx(10), true));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    prepareAlbums();

    //Cover Pic

    try {
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.project1_cover).into((ImageView) 
findViewById(R.id.backdrop));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    setupDrawerContent(navigationView);



}
public void selectedItemDrawer(MenuItem menuItem){
    Fragment myFragment = null;
    Class fragment = null;

    switch(menuItem.getItemId()){

        case R.id.checkIn:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check-In", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.checkOut:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check-Out", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.applyOff:
            break;

        case R.id.reportBug:
            break;

        case R.id.manageProfile:
            fragment = fragment_manageProfile.class;
            break;

        case R.id.logout:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    try{
        myFragment = (Fragment)fragment.newInstance();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, 
myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    drawer.closeDrawers();
}
```

**content_main xml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/viewBg"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="info.androidhive.kopilim.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**app_bar_main xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**activity_main xml file**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/login_background">
</FrameLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**PS fragmentLayout** is currently in my activity_main.xml file there. Because I not sure where it has to be. For now, everything i mean the view of my content, my layout is fined. But just for the activity in the navigation bar, fragment there is not showing. 
Where did I make my mistake?

**Edited: My fragment Class**

fragment layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="info.androidhive.kopilim.fragment_manageProfile">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textColor="#10019f"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/manageProfile"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/empEmail"
            android:text="@string/email"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/empID"
                android:hint="@string/profileID"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/empName"
                android:hint="@string/profileName"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/empIC"
                android:hint="@string/profileIC"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1"
            >

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/male"
                android:id="@+id/maleRadio"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:checked="true" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/female"
                android:id="@+id/femaleRadio"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"/>

        </RadioGroup>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/empPh"
                android:hint="@string/profileHp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/empAddress"
                android:hint="@string/profileAddress"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/profileBtn"
            android:text="@string/updateProfileBtn"
            android:background="@color/buttonLogin"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

fragment java class

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_manage_profile, container, 
false);
....
....
//my activity
return v;
}
```

Comment: What does your stack trace print? Probably, It cant create a new fragment. and What is fragment?

Comment: @salman there show no error. but just fragment cant showing. Opps, forgot to post my fragment class, I will post my fragment class here.

Answer (score 0):

FrameLayout is ok in your activity layout file because you want to display the fragment on the same screen. About the fragment displaying . You need to have a custom fragment class to show it's view and to support it's business logic.

```
public void selectedItemDrawer(MenuItem menuItem){
    Fragment myFragment = null;
    Class fragment = null;

    switch(menuItem.getItemId()){

        case R.id.checkIn:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Check-In", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.checkOut:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Check-Out", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.applyOff:
            break;

        case R.id.reportBug:
            break;

        case R.id.manageProfile:
            showMyFragment();
            break;

        case R.id.logout:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}

public void showMyFragment(){
    Fragment menuFragment = new MyCustomFragment();
       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frameLayout, menuFragment).commit();
}
```

And here you have to declare the custom fragment class :

```
public class MyCustomFragment extends Fragment {

//this text view is got from the xml below 
private TextView tvTest;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_layout, container, false);
              return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        bindView(view);

        //start your logic here
    }



    private void bindView(View view){
     tvTest = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_fragment_test);

     Toast.makeText(getContext(),tvTest.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
```

my_fragment_layout.xml

```
// could be any kind of layout
  // for example

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_fragment_test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I'm showing on a fragment"
        android:src="@drawable/app_img_small" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sry. I am still confusing this customfragment. What is the function? Can explain it in simple way ? Thanks man.

Comment: @DavidAdam sure :D. That custom fragment is created to replace the FrameLayout added in your activity. Basically the custom fragment represents the view that is created when the fragment is started. You wanted to use a fragment when you perform a click on the navigation drawer, thus , a fragment will be created when you do so , but there's no reference to any existed fragment in your code and you just create a reference to the default Fragment class that sustains no view on it. In other words the fragment has its own layout and you could treat it as "another screen".

Comment: thanks man, but how do I link my fragment activity to the custom fragment ?

Comment: Look above in the example  `public void showMyFragment(){
    Fragment menuFragment = new MyCustomFragment();
       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();` here I'm creating a new instance of the custom fragment, `Fragment menuFragment = new MyCustomFragment();` then, I do replace FrameLayout from the activity with the menuFragment that represents an instance of the custom fragment.